# How to calculate expected token amount out in a UniswapV3 swap

Tags: uniswap, decentralized-exchange, uniswapv3

Accounting for slippage, is there a good way of reading data from a UniswapV3 pair and estimate how many tokens will be received when performing a swap (accounting for slippage)?

I couldn't think of a good way of calulating this given the tick system / liquidity positions.

I want to use this to generate an accurate quote for a swap. I know Uniswap are doing it on their official website, but I'm wondering what is going on behind the scenes.

The [Qouter](https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v3/reference/periphery/lens/QuoterV2) documentation is interesting, but I would rather do a mathematical estimate rather than having to call the blockchain every time I want to estimate a swap.